# Google App Script , find file's parent id if exist in a Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to find (in a Google Sheets list of file Id) file's parent ID in a loop, until it's present in another Google Sheets. All is ok for the first parent but it doesn't work when i'm trying to get 2nd or 3rd parent's generation higher. My fileParent is "undefined" , i don't know why cause row 3 my var file return the correct first parent ID.
`

```
//all var are initialized before
var files = DriveApp.getFileById(*My File ID*);
var myFiles = files.getParents()
var file = myFiles.next().getId();

 for(var rowRef in tab_ref){
     if(file != tab_ref[rowRef][9]){  
           while(tab_ref[rowRef][9] != file && files.hasNext()){       
              var fileParent = DriveApp.getFolderById(file);
              files = fileParent.getParents();
              file = files.next().getId();
            }
            if(tab_ref[rowRef][9] == id_file){
                sheet_files.activate();
                sheet_files.getActiveCell().offset(2,10).setValue(file); 
            }
     } 
}
```

Comment: We won't be able to help as we've no idea how your table looks like. can you log/display what myFiles contain in this part of your code var myFiles = files.getParents()?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the easiest way to find what your looking but I think it is a way to do it.  I use these sorts of loops to build directory trees for access to all sorts of hierarchical data and I also incorporate JQuery jstree to create an easy to use UI for anybody that's use to navigating on a computer.  So here's the code.  If your not familiar with this kind of coding it may take you a while to figure it out.  Have fun with it.  I incorporated comments that refer to a parentsArray[].  The parentsArray[] could be used as kind of stack where you push and pop current folder names onto and off of the stack in order to keep track of your current path or parental ancestry of folders.

```
function traverseFolder(folderObj) 
{
  //parentsArray[parentsArray.length-1] is the immediate parent of the current folderObj.
  //Put folderObj name, size info here
  //Push folderobj name on to parentsArray  
  var subs = folderObj.getFolders();
  var files =  folderObj.getFiles();
  if(files)
  {
    while(files.hasNext())
    {
      var fi = files.next();;
      //Put file name,size,info here
      //parentsArray[parentsArray.length-1] is the immediate parent of all of these files
      //parentsArray[0]/parentsArray[1].../parentsArray[parentsArray.length-1] is the path to this file.
    }
  }
  while (subs.hasNext()) 
  {
    traverseFolder(subs.next());
  }
  //Pop last folderobj off of the parentsArray
}
```